# What would be the best decision for separator make-up?

Tags: css, separator

I want to insert a separator between blocks and content, that are rounded with css3 border-radius property (see the picture below). What would be the best decision for separator make-up?

[image: layout with separator]

Comment: Should the separator have any contents? If not you can just set a margin-right on sidebar

Comment: No, it must be just a line with some weight and style. But as far as I know border-radius property cuts the borders, so Iam not able to use it here.

Comment: Sounds like you either need to add unnecessary elements or if your sidebar is always X width you could use a background image on whatever contains it.  That would require an image download (or hex in the CSS).  Rock and a hard place.

Comment: thirtydot, yes. But you may tell what you think, and I'll try to use some hacks for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply a [faux column](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) approach to the parent element (#sheet?). I'm not sure if that will meet all of your requirements.

From a design point of view, if both pieces of content already are contained in a shape, would a separator really be necessary? Just seems like it would add extra clutter is all.

Comment: In fact, in this situation separator is really redundant.

Answer (score 0):

here you have good images for separators:

http://medialoot.com/item/dark-mysterius-web-design-elements/

I used it on my sites

or maybe for more ideas check this:

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/07/50-psd-ui-web-design-elements/

good luck!